# PHP Postgtres Generate CSV File for Download

Tags: php, postgresql, csv

I have a postgresql database table and using PHP for the backend. On the user interface, I provide users with a way of generating reports. What I want to do is that when a user wishes to generate a report, a CSV file should be provided for download.

I already know how to generate a CSV file for results of a query, but now in this case I don't want the file to be saved on disk. Instead, it should be downloaded by the browser.

Comment: save the file, link to the file, delete the file

Comment: Can you give some of your code, specially `generate a csv file for results of query` !?

Comment: @michael I don't need a solution for that, i need to know @Denny 's solution to try to corect/adapt to achieve what he would like to do.
And i think that the `fputcsv` is not valid for his case, because he is asking for downloading a CSV without using a temporary file.

Comment: ok, then I understood you wrong

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to provide a page for download...

```
#downloadCSV.php?reportID=1

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourfile.csv"');
// do your postgresql query and put the result into $csv
echo $csv;
```

In this way you don't have to create a real file on your server

The second header `Content-Disposition: attachment;`  forces the browser to download a file instead to show the content in a page

Comment: Yes, that's right! And perhaps better use : `header('Content-Type: application/csv');` instead